# Вектор вместо динамического массива, выгодно ли?

Tags: c++, vector

Хочу заменить постоянное выделение и освобождение памяти в методе, на

```
std::vector<unsigned char>
```

Т.е. я его объявляю, после того как узнал необходимую емкость, вызвал `std::vector<>::resize`.

Скажите, будет ли это выгодно в плане производительности, т.е. не будет ли выполняться дольше, и не понесет ли это за собой какие-то последствия, т.к. выделяемое место под данные варьируется в районе ~20 байт?

```
struct input
{
    static input                        &get_input();
    input_type                          type() const;
    mouse_input                         &mouse() const;
    keyboard_input                      &keyboard() const;

    bool initialize(const std::vector<::RAWINPUTDEVICE> &input_devices);
    bool is_initialized() const;

    ~input();

    input(const input &) = delete;
    input(const input &&) = delete;
    input& operator=(const input &) = delete;
    input& operator=(const input &&) = delete;

private:
    bool                                m_is_initialized_;
    input_type                          m_type_;
    static input                        *p_instance_;
    ::std::vector<byte>                 m_data_bytes_;
    ::std::unique_ptr<mouse_input>      p_mouse_input_;
    ::std::unique_ptr<keyboard_input>   p_keyboard_input_;

protected:
    LRESULT             process_input_data(LPARAM l_param);
    friend struct       window;

    input();
};
```

Место которое я считаю узким, это когда вызывается `process_input_data`, и запрос `GetRawInputData`, который после первого вызова, может вернуть не верное значение.

```
#include "input.h"
#include "mouse_input.h"
#include "keyboard_input.h"

input* input::p_instance_ = nullptr;

input& input::get_input()
{
    return *(p_instance_ == nullptr ? (p_instance_ = new input) : p_instance_);
}

input_type input::type() const
{
    return m_type_;
}

mouse_input& input::mouse() const
{
    return *p_mouse_input_;
}

keyboard_input& input::keyboard() const
{
    return *p_keyboard_input_;
}

bool input::initialize(const std::vector<RAWINPUTDEVICE> &input_devices)
{
    if(is_initialized())
    {
        return true;
    }

    return m_is_initialized_ = RegisterRawInputDevices(input_devices.data(), input_devices.size(), sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICE)) != FALSE;
}

bool input::is_initialized() const
{
    return m_is_initialized_;
}

input::~input() = default;

input::input() :
    m_is_initialized_(false),
    m_type_(input_type::none),
    p_mouse_input_(std::make_unique<mouse_input>()),
    p_keyboard_input_(std::make_unique<keyboard_input>())
{
}

::LRESULT input::process_input_data(const ::LPARAM l_param)
{
    ::uint32_t buffer_size = 0;

    const::HRAWINPUT raw_input = reinterpret_cast<::HRAWINPUT>(l_param);
    const::uint32_t header_size = sizeof(::RAWINPUTHEADER);

    ::GetRawInputData(raw_input, RID_INPUT, nullptr, &buffer_size, header_size);

    m_data_bytes_.resize(buffer_size);

    if (::GetRawInputData(raw_input, RID_INPUT, m_data_bytes_.data(), &buffer_size, sizeof(::RAWINPUTHEADER)) != buffer_size)
    {
        ::OutputDebugStringW(L"GetRawInputData does not return correct size !\n");
    }

    const::LPRAWINPUT raw = reinterpret_cast<const::LPRAWINPUT>(m_data_bytes_.data());

    switch (raw->header.dwType)
    {
        case RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD:
            m_type_ = input_type::keyboard;
            return p_keyboard_input_->process_input_data(&raw->data.keyboard);
        case RIM_TYPEMOUSE:
            m_type_ = input_type::mouse;
            return p_mouse_input_->process_input_data(&raw->data.mouse);
        default:
            m_type_ = input_type::none;
            return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: дольше что и чего?

Comment: Обычного `new` т.к. тут же вроде бы потребудется время на создание объекта `vector`.

Comment: не забывайте, что для распределения вектор использует стандартный распределитель, который в свою очередь  выделяет память какраз через new, и то, что вы делаете без вектора, тут делается наилучшим способом, так что вектор выгоднее, если конечно нет прчин использовать совершенно другой контейнер

Comment: почему не std::array?

Comment: @bobtorus, потому что: `std::array - это контейнер, инкапсулирующий массив фиксированного размера. `

Comment: @LLENN, и в чем проблема? выделили 20 байт и работайте, и не надо в кучу лезть

Comment: @bobtorus: Вы понимаете что мне не известно какой размер данных вернет функция `GetRawInputData`, а она может вернуть и не корректный размер.

Comment: @LLENN, тогда берите вектор, вряд ли будет большая разница

Comment: Выгодно будет переиспользовать один и тот же вектор чтобы не выделять память повторно.

Comment: Выгодней будет с точки зрения кода, писать меньше и выглядит аккуратнее, а так по логике, должно быть чуть дольше чем голый new, но это субъективно, можно ведь и проверок наталкать.. для снижения производительности :)

Comment: Чем меньше действий (любых), тем быстрее. Но без конкретного кода и описания условий его применения посоветовать что-то определенное не получится (т.е. может быть вам вообще и никакой new (или malloc) не нужен)

Comment: У меня надежда на то, что вектор не будет заново выделять память, если размер тот же.

Comment: Да, не будет. Но такое (порядка 20 байт) место в памяти проще и быстрее выделять в стеке. Только вот хорошо бы убедиться, что это вообще узкое место - преждевременная оптимизация, сами знаете...

Comment: @Harry, “Premature optimization is the root of all evil” :)